# Loaded file not generating in a listview - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am trying to write a program that can load multiple different text files, containing encrypted values, individually to create a ListView of the encryptions is the first column and the decrypted value in the second column. The problem that I am running into is that when I load a file... nothing happens. There is no error, no crash, just nothing. I believe that it is not reading the file path correctly, but I am very new to this so that is only intuition. Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub loadBtn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles loadBtn.Click

    valueList.Clear()
    valueList.Columns.Add("Encypted File", 150)
    valueList.Columns.Add("Decrypted", 100)

    Dim newFile As New OpenFileDialog()

    Try
        If newFile.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            Dim writer As New System.IO.StreamReader(newFile.FileName)
            Dim line() As String

            Do Until writer.Peek <> -1
                Dim newLine As ListViewItem
                line = writer.ReadLine.Split("="c)
                newLine.Text = line(0).ToString
                valueList.Items.Add(newLine)
                newLine.SubItems.Add(Crypto.AES_Decrypt(line(0)))
            Loop

            writer.Close()

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        valueList.Items.Add("Error reading file." & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

There is a notification in the line

```
newLine.Text = line(0).ToString
```

that the variable 'newLine' is used before it has been assigned a value. I thought that I was assigning it a value at that time but I guess I am wrong. This does not cause a runtime error, just thought I should make not of it.

Comment: `Dim newLine As ListViewItem` just declares that newLine WILL be of type ListViewItem, it is not instanced.  change that to `Dim newLine As NEW ListViewItem`.  also turn on Option Strict.  otherwise set a breakpoint and see why it doesnt enter that loop (if it did your code would result in a NullReference because of newItem).

Comment: Thank you, declaring newLine as NEW solved the empty variable, but I still have nothing happen when I try to load a file. I should have noted that I am using VB2010 and Option Strict is On.

Comment: set a breakpoint and see why it doesnt enter that loop

Comment: Wonderful! Setting a breakpoint let me see that it was in-fact loading the file, but the loop was not initializing. Changing the line `Do While writer.Peek <> -1` to `Do Until writer.Peek = -1` solved that problem. But, it is still not loading anything into the second column. Am I assigning the text to the second column incorrectly?

Comment: I usually add the LVI *after* all the subs are added to it (swap the last two lines in the loop), but check that your crypto procedure works like you think it does. also make sure that you have 2 column headers defined (sub items dont show unless there is a header)

Comment: Hmm, I have swaped the last two lines in the loop and checked my crypto procedure (to the most of my knowledge it functions the way I think it does) but I am unsure about the column headers. Am I correctly defining them through `valueList.Columns.Add("Encypted File", 150) valueList.Columns.Add("Decrypted", 100)`? If so then can it only mean that I need to study my crypto class deeper?

Comment: columns look ok - that can be done in the IDE though.  Add a variable to catch the crypto return so you can look at it in debug: `temp = Crypto.AES_Decrypt(line(0)) \\ newLine.SubItems.Add(temp))` hold your mouse over `temp` to see if has a value

Comment: Setting a breakpoint just after assigning the variable to catch the crypto shows that it is an empty variable. So, I will have to review my documentation for the crypto class and see if I can figure out what is wrong. I will update the thread for anyone that is following and if anyone has additional ideas I am open to suggestion.